# Most efficient way to create reports compiling many PHP data arrays organized by date

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, report

I'm using PHP and I am pulling in data from a few different datasources:

1. Data from Google Analytics
2. Data from our MySQL database
3. Data from our ElasticSearch system

The result is I have 8 or so PHP arrays for a 30 day period. Some arrays have 30 elements each representing a day in the 30 day period, and some have fewer rows (because there was no activity for a particular day.)

What is the smartest way for me to tabulate the data? The most straight forward solution I thought of was to loop through the days for the report (i.e., `for($startDate = x, $startDate < $endDate, $startDate + 1 day)`) and then for each day find the corresponding value in each array. The problem with this approach is that I'll have a `for` loop 30 times, and each loop will loop through 8 arrays of data up to 30 times...

Any suggestions?

Sample arrays: http://bin.cakephp.org/view/953092822

Answer (score 1):

A bit dirty solution, but I think it's appropriate. A piece of code to illustrate the general idea:

```
$date1 = '2011-12-19';
$date2 = '2011-12-20';
$date3 = '2011-12-21';
$array1 = array($date1=>array('res1'=>'asdasdasd'),$date2=>array('res1'=>'qweqweqweqwe'));
$array2 = array($date1=>array('res2'=>'123123123'),$date3=>array('res2'=>'456456456'));

$res = array_merge_recursive($array1,$array2);
var_dump($res);
```

So, the idea is to have your arrays store the data in elements with unique keys, and than use `array_merge_recursive` to have all that data collected. So, to get it working you'll need to preprocess your data with something like that:

```
$arr = array($date1=>'qweqwe', $date2=>'asdasd');

foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
    $arr[$key]=array('<unique source name here>'=>$value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the data arrays first and transform them to some unified format, indexed by dates. After that - everything depends on how you want to display the data, but since it will then be date-indexed, it should be better to handle in any way that you could think of.